# Block Facebook newsfeed on OS level (for any browser) without blocking social login buttons

Tags: windows, macos, browser

I'm looking for a way to block Facebook newsfeed browsing (in any browser, so browser proxy settings are not an option here), but still give user ability to use social login buttons/API. I've tried modifying hosts file, but this blocks the entire domain and I cannot specify any specify URL path that must continue working.

Would appreciate ideas for both: Windows and OSx machines.

Comment: What do you mean with social login buttons?

Comment: Here I mean "Login with Facbook" buttons on websites that utilize Facbook API calls. I want users to have ability login with Facebook and use the API calles (www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?app_id=...), but not access the New Feed (just www.facebook.com/). I need HTTP request filtering, not IP or port blocking. And I need to control it programmatically yo change the rules on the run (from time to time).